# Rounded corners opacity transition bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, opacity, rounded-corners

Hi I just found a chrome bug.

I have a element, with an overlay in it.
When i hover it i want the overlay to fade in with css.

I've done it like this:
http://codepen.io/iamrane/pen/AraJF

But if you look with chrome you can see that the border radius dissapear when i hover it.
This is because im fading with opacity. But if you change opacity: 0 to opacity: 1. You'll see the rounded corners. So the css is not wrong.

How can i solve this is a different way if I want the fade in effect (no js answers please)

Comment: i found out that this has nothing to do with opacity.. same with top.. i tried transition from top: -100% and top: 0; Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `@include border-radius(10px);` to `.my-overlay` works in Chrome

```
.my-overlay {
    @include transition(opacity 0.2s ease);
    @include box-shadow(inset 0 0 10em 7em #000);
    @include border-radius(10px);
    opacity: 0; // Switch this to 1 to see that it works
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Strange, i thought i tested that, but I must have made a typo.. thanks.

Comment: wtf syntax is that? @include? doesn't work with style attribute.

Comment: @momomo If I remember correctly, the syntax used in the original codepen was SASS. so yes, indeed, this won't work with style attributes.

Comment: @JeroenW Ok, could not see sass tags. Less user here, waiting for a switch :(